# Allow / Restrict specific HTTP METHODS at AWS elb level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is it possible to restrict specific HTTP METHODS at elb level?
 we want to allow only HTTP GET through AWS elb.

I checked AWS docs and googled but didn’t find any appropriate solution.

If it is not possible, is there any other AWS component using which we can achieve it?
We just want to restrict GET calls alone go through ELB , so that the consumers can only retrieve data.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This needs to be handled in your web server configuration -- not ELB, not anywhere in another service.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot achieve HTTP method restriction from load balancer. But you can achieve that using AWS Cloud Front.

What you can do is create a Cloud Front distribution using the ELB as the origin and select just the GET method in the "Allowed HTTP Method" in Cloud Front Distribution setting. Check screenshot below.

[image]